# Nativescript Routing example from real world -Tabs with Modals, Modals over Modals and all in modules

Tags: angular, nativescript, router, nativescript-angular

I try to find out the way how to create modules, which is able to open in modal with options to navigate inside. Opened in TabView outlets or from another modal. like it demonstrated on this pic:

[image]

I found lots of simple examples, but if I combine together with modules - I keep wobbling around the same errors like

- Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'xy'
- Error: Cannot load module... etc
- or app just don't start

**I have prepared playground** 
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=7Pfmcl&v=4

---

**My inspirations:**

https://www.nativescript.org/blog/implementing-a-login-for-nativescript-apps-with-tab-based-navigation - it already solved login, welcome, and tabview

https://medium.com/@williamjuan027/nativescript-angular-lazy-loading-modals-e56451392c8d - lazyloading modal

---

Could someone please help me? do you have so experience with some advanced routing in nativescript with angular

Thank you so much,
Michal

Comment: Since you have named outlets in tabs page, the `nsRouterLink` you have in the welcome page should contain path info for each outlet.

Comment: Hello Manoj, outlet in tabview is not a problem  - (updated version https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=7Pfmcl&v=4) but next step - add the modal for an item makes me mad... 

NavigationError(id: 6, url: '/tabs/default/(playerTab:players/player/1//teamTab:teams/teams)(modal:items)', error: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'items') 

- Do you please know, how to handle this path? (in playground?v4 it is -> go to welcome -> go to tab -> detail player 1-> modal link)

Comment: I haven't tried modal above tab view (named outlets), looks like it may have issues. You might want to open a issue at [Github](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular) along with the Playground sample.